# Windows 10: `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

Hi I am running rails on windows 10 and when running the command

```
rspec spec/
```

I receive the following error

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:105:in `setup'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Note: I am running the command from the project folder

Comment: is your spec_helper.rb defined in the spec/ directory ? or somewhere else ?

Comment: I noticed the spec_helper.rb was missing so i created the project directory again.
I am now seeing a different error:
`You must 'gem install win32console' to use colour on Windows
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/assertions (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in block in require'`

the gem win32console is already installed.